# Getting into deadlock while using rowcount delete query

Tags: sap-ase, rowcount

```
Set rowcount 50000
declare @i int 
select @i = 1 
 WHILE ( @i > 0 )
    BEGIN
    DELETE table1
    FROM table1 (index index1)
    WHERE
    HIST_Timestamp < '2011/11/26'
    select @i = @@rowcount
    END
```

The query sometimes encounters a deadlock situation and terminates.. Not able to figure out what is going wrong .. Please help me!

Answer (score 1):

A deadlock occurs when transaction A locks a record then has to wait for transaction B to unlock a record, while transaction B is waiting on a record already locked by transaction A.

If you really want to know why the deadlock is happening, you can do it with this command:
`sp_configure "print deadlock information", 1`

Creating a useful `index` for the query allows the `delete` statement to use page or row locks, improving concurrent access to the table. If creating an `index` for the delete transaction is not possible, you can perform the operation in a cursor, with frequent commit transaction statements to reduce the number of page locks.